# Creating a project with visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

Ok, I am coming from visual studio 2015 where I could create a new site, add folders for HTML, CSS, and JS.

Switched to visual studio 2017 (Enterprise) to see what its all about and now I can not figure out how to do the same thing as 2015. I just want a blank project with the ability to add whatever file formats I want. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Also I have tried the asp.net project type, but it comes with a bunch of pre loaded nonsense.