# Visual Studio 2017 - How to create a project from the source using CMake?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, compilation, visual-studio-2017

I have a pretty large software library using CMake to be compiled. We use Linux mostly, but now a new colleague wants to use Visual Studio.

**Is there any way to create a new VS 2017 project from the existing source codes with CMake structure?**

I know, it's possible to do it with CLion, but I have no idea about VS, as I have a very little experience with it.

Other questions seem to focus on creating an empty project, which will use CMake, but not on creating a project from already existing source files.

- [Creating a cmake project with visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46741850/creating-a-cmake-project-with-visual-studio)
- [Creating a project with visual studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50594877/creating-a-project-with-visual-studio-2017)

Comment: You don't mean `cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017"` to generate a project do you? Because you say you already are using cmake on Linux, why wouldn't you just use the same 'CMakeLists.txt` and everything to generate the project?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do it. CMake is very good at this. The C in CMake stands for Cross-Platform, in fact! You open the CMake project in Visual Studio, try to compile it, if you run into platform specific problems, you modify CMakeLists.txt to compensate with platform specific branching.

Comment: @CinderBiscuits I know about cross-platform compilation. Would you mind to write a short answer about this specific IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you asked for details but...

Assuming you are using cmake 3.13 then you can do the following in a command shell:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" -S path_to_source -B path_to_build
```

This will then create a solution file.  Actually it creates a solution file for every `project()` command that is issued in `CMakeLists.txt`.

You can then open the solution file in `Visual Studio`, and build the project as usual.

You don't even need to do this in the `Visual Studio` GUI.  After creating the initial project you can also issue the command:

```
cmake --build path_to_build
```

Which will kick off the build at the command line.

Now if your `CMakeLists.txt` in path_to_source is using Linux specific libraries or `gcc` specific compiler settings then the `CMakeLists.txt` will have to get updated to the Windows equivalent.

The alternative is to start `Visual Studio` and then use `File->Open->CMake` and open the `CMakeLists.txt` file in path_to_source.  It'll then start to generate the project.  But I prefer using the command line method.